# Keep rotating CSS animation level

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 width: 20px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: green;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transform-origin: 10px 10px;
 animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotate(-30deg);}
 to {transform: rotate(30deg);}
}

hr {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```

But I want something like this:

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 width: 20px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: green;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transform-origin: 10px 10px;
 animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate, translate 0.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotate(-30deg);}
 to {transform: rotate(30deg);}
}

@keyframes translate {
 from {top: 10px;}
 to {top: 0px;}
}

hr {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```

EDIT: I probably didn't explain this well enough. What I meant is, is there a way to keep the bottom of the div touching the line witout using any sort of animation to move it up and down? I want it to be dynamic, so that if I change the value of the rotation, I won't have to calculate and change the value of the translation.

EDIT2: Simply put: I just want the div to do what the second example is doing without needing a specific value for the vertical movement.

Comment: Do what without what? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you animate its length at the same time?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uooczh9p/

Comment: You want it to stay at the same height? (doesn't move vertically?)

Answer (score 2):

You should play with values to get it perfect but this is the idea:

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 width: 20px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: green;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transform-origin: 10px 10px;
 animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 0% {transform: rotate(-30deg); top: 10px;}
 50% {top: 0px;}
 100% {transform: rotate(30deg); top: 10px;}
}

hr {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: on the 50% you dont need to set a rotate value

Comment: You need it actually, because of the interpolations if you remove that it will change...

Comment: ... You actually need to change the `animation-timing-function` of the rotation at 50%

Comment: Turns out you don't need the `animation-timing-function` so yes you are correct

Comment: xD ok, just startet looking, if there is a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what do you expect, but I will give it a try.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate, stretch 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 99px;
  width: 99%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    height: 112px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 112px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```